# WinPython: ImportError: No module named %name%

Tags: python, import, module, pythonpath

1. I installed WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2
2. I installed it not into default directory C:\Python, but into a different one like C:\"....My path...."\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2.
3. I downloaded a specific python project with all of its files and modules and placed this folder in Python folder so it has path like: C:\"....My path...."\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\project
4. I added this path to the system path like this:

   > > import sys
   > >     sys.path.append("C:\"....My path...."\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\project")
5. There is an setup.py file in the project folder which I can't seem to run - whenever i type python setup.py I get an error: **SyntaxError: invalid syntax**
6. Whenever I try to import some module from this project I get the message ImportError: **No module named %module_name%**
7. I tried this both from Spyder and Ipython console.
8. I've read some stuff about system variables and their altering, however I do not seem to have "pythonpath" variable defined, do i need to define it? What do I put in it?

Its weird, because yesterday I was able to import the exact same module, but today I already can't. I couldn't find out what is the problem here and don't seem to remeber the exact steps I performed the day before. So am asking for qualified help. This is my first time using Python.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Answer (score 0):

suppose there is a Project\setup.py

launch WinPython Command Prompt.exe

cd/D "C:\"....My path...."\WinPython-64bit-3.5.1.2\project"

python setup.py install

and, then, to check it's there:

pip list